# Can't figure out intersections between two binary numbers for a certain hamming distance

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binary

I am making a mistake somewhere in my calculation:

say I have two numbers: **00000** and **11110**

Then I find out each of their **HD=4** values:

For 00000 the list is:

> 5C4 possibilities

For 11110 the list is:

> 5C4 possibilities

My calculation for their intersecting elements comes to 2 based on:

(2C1)*(3C3)=2

But I manually found out all the possibilities and it is 0; Where am I wrong ?

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you want the set oh numbers that are distance 4 from either of these two?

Comment: Where did you get your calculation from?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes the total number of intersecting numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The number of strings with a fixed hamming distance from a given string will always be the same.

Strings of hamming distance $4$ from $00000$ will need at least four ones since you need to switch at least four of the digits. Similarly, strings of hamming distance $4$ from $11110$ will need at least three zeros (or at most two ones): since we only have $5$ digits to work with, we can't satisfy both conditions simultaneously. Hence the intersection is empty.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any general way to express this? For say different number of bits and HDs?

Comment: Also, may I ask for the first line to be rephrased please? I am having a hard time to understand; sorry.